# Selected page tab background overflowing in Blogger

Tags: html, css, navbar, blogger

I've spent a bit of time on getting my navbar above my header and getting it to spread the width of my blog at [Boy Full of Books](http://www.boyfullofbooks.blogspot.com/)

However, I'm having two problems. The main problem is evident on the blog - the selected tab's background is overflowing on to the page and not staying with the rest of the navbar. The other problem isn't one I'm terribly worried about, but if anyone has any guidance it'd be great. When zoomed out or in, the page tabs in the navbar don't adjust with the size of the page.

Below is my code (it's not great, I know, I'm still a novice):

```
.PageList {  
text-align:center !important;  
width: 100%;  
}

.PageList ul {
margin-top: -42px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: -20px;
background-color: #424242 !important;
width: 100%;
}

.PageList li {
display:inline !important; 
float:none !important;
font-size: 61.5px;
margin-left: 0px;
font-family: 'Verdana', Arial, sans-serif !important;
width: 100%;
}

.PageList a {
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none !important;
width: 100%;
}

.PageList a:hover {
background-color: #aeadad;
width: 100%;
}

.PageList li.selected {
background-color: #aeadad !important;
text-decoration: none !important;
margin-bottom: -20px !important;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.
instead

```
.PageList li.selected{
  background-color: #aeadad !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  margin-bottom: -20px !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

to

```
.PageList li.selected a {
  background-color: #aeadad !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  margin-bottom: -20px !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

2. use https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Thanks, this solved it! Not sure what to do with all the info about media queries yet, but maybe I'll understand after a while. Thank you.